# How to secure backend to backend api consumption in azure

Tags: azure, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using azure cloud and its various service. My application has some endpoints that i want to expose. Some other backend services will consumes my api and that should be in secure manner. Any already available azure service for secure communication between my api and who will consume it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the you are looking for the Api Management, it's what I use on my work to expose Apis for third parties!

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/#overview

Comment: Thanks for update. Does this will also gives security to api. Third party backend api will not be registered on azure cloud. so their backend api will call to my backend api. May be using client secrets or using token. Only api management will suffice my requirement?

Comment: Yes, you are gonna to expose your api on Api management and all calls made by the client will be through the APIM. Read and study this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/transform-api